# Form is not submitting when clicking button - onclick="this.form.submit()"

Tags: html, express, mongoose

My form is not submitting when I click a button. It was working fine but I don't know why it stoped working. It does not console anything on log. I do not have an input type submit as I am operating with a button using the **onclick** method.

Here is my HTML code (wrapped in a table):

```
<tbody>
                    <% produtos.forEach(function(produto){ %>
                        <tr>
                            <form action="/deleteProduto" method="POST"></form>
                                <td><%= produto._id %></td>
                                <td><%= produto.nomeProduto %> </td>
                                <td><%= produto.marcaProduto %> </td>
                                <td><%= produto.categoriaProduto %> </td>
                                <td><%= produto.descricaoProduto %></td>
                                <td><span>R$ </span><%= produto.precoUnitario %></td>
                                <td><%= produto.quantidadeEstoque %></td>
                                <td><%= produto.condicaoProduto %></td>
                                <td class="actions">
                                  <a href="/editarProduto" name="editButton" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="<%=produto._id%>">Editar</a>
                                  <button name="deleteButton" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="<%=produto._id%>" onclick="this.form.submit()">Remover</button>
                                </td>
                            </form>
                        </tr>
                    <%})%>
                </tbody>
```

Here is the backend:

```
app.post("/deleteProduto", function(req,res){

const clickedItem = req.body.deleteButton;
console.log("clicado");
Produto.findByIdAndDelete({_id: clickedItem}, function(err){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }else{
        res.redirect("/adm");
    }
})
```

})

I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I could think a bit more and I could resolve it by adding an Id to the form and finding it on the onclick form method.

So it got like this:

```
<form action="/deleteProduto" method="POST" id="deleteProductForm"></form>
                                <td><%= produto._id %></td>
                                <td><%= produto.nomeProduto %> </td>
                                <td><%= produto.marcaProduto %> </td>
                                <td><%= produto.categoriaProduto %> </td>
                                <td><%= produto.descricaoProduto %></td>
                                <td><span>R$ </span><%= produto.precoUnitario %></td>
                                <td><%= produto.quantidadeEstoque %></td>
                                <td><%= produto.condicaoProduto %></td>
                                <td class="actions">
                                  <a href="/editarProduto" name="editButton" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="<%=produto._id%>">Editar</a>
                                  <button name="deleteButton" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="<%=produto._id%>" onclick="document.querySelector('#deleteProductForm').submit()">Remover</button>
                                </td>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you avoid the issue altogether by just making the button have a type of submit?

```html
<button type="submit" name="deleteButton" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="<%=produto._id%>">Remover</button>
```

Comment: I am afraid not. I've just tried it and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a JavaScript reference to `this` inside an HTML attribute like that. Instead, you need to create and then reference a method in JavaScript that selects the form in the DOM and then submits it.

Eg.,

```html
<button name="deleteButton" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="<%=produto._id%>" onclick="submitForm()">Remover</button>

[...]

<script>
function submitForm() {
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  form.submit();
}
</script>
```

But if you're not doing anything to transform the data, you can just get rid of the `onsubmit` attribute altogether and replace it with `type="submit"` which does the same thing.

That being said, your `form` isn't a valid form. These are table cells, not form fields.

```html
<td><%= produto._id %></td>
<td><%= produto.nomeProduto %> </td>
<td><%= produto.marcaProduto %> </td>
<td><%= produto.categoriaProduto %> </td>
<td><%= produto.descricaoProduto %></td>
<td><span>R$ </span><%= produto.precoUnitario %></td>
<td><%= produto.quantidadeEstoque %></td>
<td><%= produto.condicaoProduto %></td>
```

What you want to do is:

```html
<td><input name="id" value="<%= produto._id %>" /></td>
<td><input name="nomeProduto" value="<%= produto.nomeProduto %>" /> </td>
[etc...]
```

Comment: Open up the browser devtools and go to the Network pane. Refresh the page and then click your submit button. Look to see if the form was submitted and inspect the body to see if your data was sent with it.

Comment: Wait — your form isn't a valid form.